# Protractor: working with canvas element - ng-if / ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm new with protractor and angular JS page.

For my end2end testing I need validated if my canvas has been received at least one image 
(There's a websocket.io thats populate some images in this canvas).

For now I should validate just if canvas starts received that images.

My html page:

```html
<div class="terminal-screenshots" ng-class="{ online: isConnected() && vm.hasImage }">
        <canvas ng-show="isConnected() && vm.hasImage" style="width: 100%;" id="remoteTerminalCanvas"></canvas>
        <span ng-if="!isConnected() || !vm.hasImage">
          {{ vm.display.message | translate }}
        </span>
</div>
```

This is my expect:

```
expect(element(by.id('remoteTerminalCanvas')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

But it's return true before the first image show up in the canvas.

Comment: I haven't worked much with canvas but would the height of canvas change after the image is populated? If so, you could use `browser.wait()` to wait until the height of canvas is larger than zero.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the answer :D

Do you have a example about it ? (validated if canvas is larger than zero)

Comment: @alecxe's answer is exactly what I had in mind. Let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

As @finspin noted, your `canvas` element might be always visible, but be of a 0 height at the same time. You can wait for the `height` value to be more than zero via [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and [`getSize()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getSize):

```
var canvas = element(by.id('remoteTerminalCanvas'));
browser.wait(function () {
    return canvas.getSize().then(function (size) { 
        return size.height > 0;
    });
}, 5000);
```

Another option is to wait for the `hasImage` to become true via [`browser.wait()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and [`evaluate()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate):

```
var canvas = element(by.id('remoteTerminalCanvas'));
browser.wait(function () {
    return canvas.evaluate("vm.hasImage").then(function (hasImage) { 
        return hasImage;
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer !

The first option was worked fine for me. But I think the second option is better because use hasImage to check if canvas received at least one image.
But when I ran my spec I'm facing this error wirh evaluate method

   - Failed: unknown error: Cannot read property '$eval' of undefined
  
I can provide the full stack if you want

thanks

Comment: @GuilhermeLeindecker hm, have not seen this kind of error before. Are you on the latest Protractor? What if you change the `vm.hasImage` to `vm && vm.hasImage`?..

Comment: protractor --version
Version 4.0.14
Google Chrome version: 54
Code
return canvas.evaluate('vm && vm.hasImage')

same error